# Is it possible to create PDF from code instead of HTML to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

The only way I've ever seen PDF generation done on the web is HTML to PDF conversion. In my experience that can have lots of issues where things don't turn out as you expect. And the quality of the result is highly dependent on the library used.

So my question is simply:
Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you didn't even mention your preferred language

Comment: There are several PDF library tools that let you create PDF by just creating and adding objects to the page. Some even have rudimentary layout engines that will handle line breaks, columns, table generation, etc. What environment are you most comfortable working in?

Comment: I want to avoid having this question become a 'what's the best x for y' type of question because those always get closed. I wasn't sure there was any way to do this except HTML to PDF conversion. Now it seems clear there are options. So I am happy with this as is. However, Java, Javascript/Node and C# are my top three languages of choice...

Answer (score -1):

A PDF is just a special encoded version of encapsulated post script. SO YES in principle. Post script is text based. So look out for a eps 2 pdf converter and you are "done". If you ar lucky and run linux or some other unix which has CUPS as a printer driver you can utilize CUPS to do that. There are also some HTML to PDF converters aou. Look at github. They do more or less in the last stage nothing else. Ah not to mention ghostscript or TEX LATEX. Which also can produce PDF. So YES, it can be done. But the afford is not minimal. I have taken one look in the EPS and PDF documentation. I got the same idea. And i forget this idea very fast ;) [eps to svg converter](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm) [Github pdf generator sources](https://github.com/search?q=pdf%20generator)

Comment: PDF isn't anything like encapsulated PostScript (EPS). PDF is random access, EPS is linear for starters.